# Why and when to use AJAX base navegation

Tags: javascript, ajax

i saw this AJAX technique of navegation where liks go to /#!example, is this ajax navegation? why and when to use it?. do you know where can i learn it? tutorial or some thing?

Comment: Hashes indicate nothing in particular about the implementation of a website. This is too broad of a question for Stack Overflow. Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Search google for AJAX and examples of how AJAX is used.

Comment: And that way of state management is outdated thanks to HTML5 history api.

Answer (score 1):

The Ajax Based Page Navigation:  /#!example
You provided this thing, on the basis of that thing I come to know that you were asking about Angular JS page routes.

AngularJS is actually used for Single Page Application, when you don't want to actually load whole page and render it again in browser, at that time you can use this type of page navigation.

It actually load the HTML in your main template and your page is not totally refreshing and loading again. In normal HTML, we click on anchor tag and it redirect us to the #tag.

eg.

```
<a href="#goto"> Goto Bottom </a>

<div id="goto">This is Bottom</div>
```

When you clicked "Goto Bottom", you direct go to the page bottom, and your page url look like this.

```
http://localhost/pageName.html#goto
```

The same concept is implemented extensively by angular js.

ex.

```
<body>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

In above sample code, at the place of "div" having "ng-view", your actual HTML will load.

and url routing for that is just like below

```
$routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl : "home.html"});
```

When you write above route code, your application url in browser will generate like this

```
http://localhost/#/home
```

Try angular js documentation here